# Magento 2 product pages renders very slow

Tags: magento2

I have a magento 2.3 intance with 277.000 product. Most of them are simple products. I have an external website with links to products.

Problem is when user is redirected from an external page to product page on Magento, for the first time it renders very, very slow. When user goes once again, request is much faster, probably because page is cached. Is there any way to increase performance of loading product pages in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. Some pages are not cached so they render slow on first visit.

It's not directly my area of expertise in Magento but I think warming a page cache is one of the solution here: https://www.mageplaza.com/review/full-page-cache/

https://amasty.com/docs/doku.php?id=magento_2:full_page_cache_warmer

I guess it is also worth to check if there are not any other issues with rendering a product page. Perhaps there are some modification that slow down it and it could be fixed.

So anyway it would be good if some backend developer would check it.

Comment: The "page warmer" extension is not a viable solution at all. It takes 2 hours and 10 minutes to warm up 8,000 products. If you want to warm up 270,000 products, it would take 66 hours (more than 2 days). This is the limitation of Magento.